# Creating a PKCanvasView in swiftUI makes the screen flickers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

I have a SwiftUI view that uses a PKCanvasView
However, I am receiving an error in the logs

> 2023-05-07 01:06:14.413211-0700 [24247:15704822] Metal API Validation
> Enabled
>
> 2023-05-07 01:06:16.157795-0700 [24247:15705030] [] Failed to allocate
> an IOSurface, falling back to a regular framebuffer to avoid crashing.
>
> 2023-05-07 01:06:18.096437-0700 [24247:15704904] [] Failed to allocate
> an IOSurface, falling back to a regular framebuffer to avoid crashing.

here's my CanvasView

```swift
struct DrawingCanvasView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var canvas: PKCanvasView
    let drawingPolicy: PKCanvasViewDrawingPolicy

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PKCanvasView {
        canvas.drawingPolicy = drawingPolicy
        return canvas
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PKCanvasView, context: Context) {

    }
}
```

and here's the view

```
struct ExpereinceDrawingContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: ExperienceDrawingContentViewModel

    init(viewModel: ExperienceDrawingContentViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    var body: some View {
        DrawingCanvasView(canvas: $viewModel.canvas, drawingPolicy: .anyInput)
            .onAppear(perform: viewModel.handleViewDidLoad)
            .navigationTitle("Draw")
            .toolbar {
                Button("Done") {
                    viewModel.handleDone()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

here's what's happening in the UI

[image]

Comment: I see similar. Only, after getting the metal API error the drawing view doesn't render unless I am actively drawing. When I draw I see it. When I do not draw, no drawing is visible. However, on device it behaves as expected.